# How to reload UITableView frequently with data coming through web services

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview

I am using web services to get data from. I am implementing a `UItextField` as a search bar.

When user type any character in search bar the web service is called and with newly parsed data I update the `NSMutableArray` object.

But there is a problem, when I typed any single character in search bar, web service is get called and before reloading `UITableVIew`, another web service is called in Background, as user types another character for search.

I want to know that what should be the work flow for this and which methods should I use as I am new to iOS.

Comment: As user typed and requestA in progress in background, after user type again, before making new requestB cancel previous requestA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used to solve this problem by delaying the call to the service until the user stops typing. Now, you can't really get an event that the user has stopped typing, but what you can do is measure the time from when the last character was entered using an NSTimer. The algorithm would be something like this.

- user presses the keyboard.
- an NSTimer is set to fire after 0.7 seconds and trigger a web
  request.
- user presses the keyboard after 0.5 seconds, the previous timer is reset to fire again after 0.7  seconds
- user stops writing, and the timer fires a method which cancels the previous request if any and requests new data for text field entry.

This also ensures that you don't poll your server with too many requests. Note that 0.7 seconds is a magic number which worked really well for our case :)